# Setting field value's according to user input in a custom form?

Tags: entities

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Setting field value’s according to user input in a custom form?](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/53814/setting-field-values-according-to-user-input-in-a-custom-form)

i am using drupal 7 FAPI to create nodes through a custom form. the code below creates the nodes and assign them with a title and a body, so if i wanted static field values everything was perfect. my problem is, i want the value of `$body_text` to be determined by the user's input in the "order" textfield. i tried doing something like -

```
$body_text = $form['name'];
```

but that didn't work.

this is the code i'm using -

```
<?php
function nodeform_menu() {
  $items = array();
  $items['nodeform/form'] = array(
    'title' => t('My form'),
    'page callback' => 'nodeform_form',
    'access arguments' => array('access content'),
    'description' => t('My form'),
    'type' => MENU_CALLBACK,
  );
  return $items;
}

function nodeform_form() {
  return drupal_get_form('nodeform_my_form');

}

function nodeform_my_form($form, &$form_state) {

  $form['box'] = array(
    '#type' => 'markup',
    '#prefix' => '<div id="box">',
    '#suffix' => '</div>',
    '#markup' => '<h1>Initial markup for box</h1>',
  );

    $form['order'] = array(
    '#type' => 'textfield',
    '#title' => t('My order'),
    '#default_value' => 'Products',
  );

  $form['submit'] = array(
    '#type' => 'submit',
    '#ajax' => array(
      'callback' => 'ajax_example_submit_driven_callback',
      'wrapper' => 'box',
      'name' => 'submit1',
    ),
    '#value' => t('Submit'),
  );



$body_text = $form['order'];
$node = new StdClass();
$node->type = 'page';
$node->status = 1;
$node->title = "name";
  $node->language = LANGUAGE_NONE;
  $node->body[$node->language][0]['value']   = $body_text; 
  $node->language = LANGUAGE_NONE;

node_save($node);
  return $form;
}
```

can anyone help me understand how to do this? i tried googling and reading the FAPI guide's but couldn't figure it out... plus, this is the first time i am using FAPI so in-spite the code is working, if anyone have any insights on this code (such as coding it more properly) i would also very appreciate that. thanks a lot!

Comment: $node->body[language][0]['value']   = $body_text;